# static text : field value next to it

Tags: jasper-reports

I have this jasper report, i have a static text 'Age:'  Next to it , I want to display the age value. How do i do it?

Thanks

```
<staticText>
            <reportElement x="-1" y="36" width="485" height="14" uuid="407bce21-d146-488f-bade-d7e7da9aaa1f"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Age:]]></text>
        </staticText>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to print the value of age, that is either a parameter, field, or a variable. I assume it is a field, so you are receiving the age via the query.

So, you want something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="9f81b54d-9940-4881-9423-adc74f27cece">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select 9 as age from dual]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="AGE" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="14" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="407bce21-d146-488f-bade-d7e7da9aaa1f" x="0" y="0" width="25" height="14"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Age:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="904205c6-35ae-4338-bae6-795f0d583f89" x="25" y="0" width="68" height="14"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{AGE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: It is also possible to put both (static text and value) into one entity. Then you must use a textfield instad of a static text field. The Text Field Expression then would be this: `"Age: " + $F{AGE}`

Comment: thanks. this works. However, if the textField is applied <textElement>
     <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
    </textElement> it doesnt evaluate the expression. why is that?

Comment: This is a question I cannot answer any more. It has been a very long time since I was working with reports last time. Sorry, mate.

Comment: I resolved it. but i do not know how i did it. I was hard coding it to no avail. Then i used the visual editor and dragged an existing text field to create a new one and it worked.

Comment: You can clone the file and hard code it again. Then open a diff to find out whether the second approach did something differently.